# On shutdown I'm getting "you don't have permission to shut down this computer" message

Tags: windows-7, windows

Running Sony Vaio Win 7, logged on as administrator and suddenly getting "You don't have permission to shut down this computer" message on shutdown and/or restart attempt.

Comment: Is this machine connected to an active directory domain?

Comment: Is another user logged ON as Administrator and doing something.  Log OFF and look at the list to log back on

Comment: This is a recent issue, presumably with a recent W7 update - You can find reference to it on Google news for example, e.g. https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-7-bug-prevents-users-from-shutting-down-or-rebooting-computers/

Comment: Check the article provided. It is not affecting my own Windows 7 Pro Virtual Machine, so it is not affecting all (or even a majority of) machines at this point. Be sure to fully restart your computer

Comment: It's a relatively new "bug" with Windows 7.  Some are blaming Microsoft, some are blaming a possible Adobe update messing with something.  The article posted a few comments up gives a workaround for "fixing" the shutdown issue, but I feel that the problem is deeper than that.  I run some development stuff, and not to go into details, but I have more things now "broken" on my machine that have been working fine for years that now require me to right-click and do the "Run as Administrator" thing to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm using a Windows 7 on Bootcamp, this method worked for me and might work on any type.

1. Open the Run dialog by hitting the Windows+R combo or click Start and type run to access it; type gpedit.msc and hit OK or press enter/return.
2. Go to Computer Settings > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options
3. Search User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account and set it to ENABLE.

All the best!

Answer (score -1):

Disable the 3 Adobe services, Adobe Genuine Monitor Service, Adobe Update and Adobe Genuine Software Integrity Service. This has resolved the issue on several PC's I have worked on